# BackboneJS v/s CanJS which one is better?

Tags: backbone.js, canjs

I'm confused between the two choice which one to use BackboneJS/CanJS for my next project. Can anyone suggest which one is better ?

Comment: We would probably need to know a little more about your project. For example how many different interactions there would be and the complexity required. But if your just asking for my opinion, I like can.js better as it's a lot cleaner and simpler to read/write and has view logic built in. The main problem with can.js currently is there is not as many examples available to get your read around how it works. But that being said backbone.js is a lot more detailed and you would have a hard time with it if you were new to javascript also.

Answer (score 5):

They have many similarities and differences, here are some:

Similarities

- They both have models that can be observed, they use similar patterns for setting attributes
- CanJS has Controls which in are quite similar to Views in Backbone, you listen to events in similar way in both
- They are both small and very flexible
- Routing in quite similar in both, Backbone has a special Router object while in CanJS you do the routing inside a Control class, but they are quite similar
- I found that many of the patterns of doing things in Backbone are translatable to CanJS

Differences:

- Backbone has a huge community, tons of plug-ins for doing about anything
- You are likely to find more documentation and help when using Backbone
- Backbone doesn't have a prescribed way of doing things e.g. rendering views. So this can be good or bad, depending on how you see it. Many time it leads to many projects doing things totally different when using Backbone.
- Backbone doesn't implement view rendering or two way bindings, is up to you to implement that somehow
- CanJS has reactive views using EJS or Mustache, so there is a defined way of doing this, it also has two way bindings
- CanJS has components
- CanJS is quite good at avoiding memory leaks, if you follow certain patterns, for example if you are listening for a window resize event inside a control, when you remove the control from the DOM CanJS will also remove the listeners automatically, in Backbone you have to do more manual work